# Learning Resource Question - Computable General Equilibrium Modelling

Tags: self-study, general-equilibrium

Several years after graduation, I would like to learn some practical computable general equilibrium (CGE) modelling such as a CGE that can handle distributional outcomes.

Does anyone know of open-access resources available for this kind of modelling or any accessible tutorials?

And also, if someone is particularly knowledgable in this area, would they be able to confirm the most common CGE software used by researchers, whether GAMS or otherwise?

Would love to hear some feedback.

Comment: I know firsthand that many government institutions use GAMS. I have encountered researchers using Matlab as well as GAMS. It comes down to personal preference unless you are tailoring your skills for a specific job. I am not that knowledgeable so take it with a grain of salt.